# mat-grid-tile resizing using mouse drag

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a base HTML like this which creates a layout for the app

```html
<div>
<mat-grid-list cols="12" rowHeight="100px">
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="3" rowspan="9">
        <left-nav></left-nav>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="9" rowspan="4">
        <right-top-nav></right-top-nav>
    </mat-grid-tile>
    <mat-grid-tile colspan="9" rowspan="5">
        <right-bottom-nav></right-bottom-nav>
    </mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

Now, I want the capability of resizing the right-bottom-nav tile on mouse drag with a max and min-height.

[image: Broken grid]

Is there a way to support this with Mat-Grid?

Comment: have you checked the official documentation?

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/api 
Yes I have checked the above link, but could not find anything relevant

Comment: Have you fix your issue ?